# Replacing an iframe with a Webview in an iOS Cordova Project

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, webview, wkwebview

I am currently developing a hybrid app in iOS that loads a website and has some other features (contacts, sharing, notifications...) using cordova plugins.  I do have access to the content of the site that is being displayed by the iframe.

The normal way this is done is to load the website in an iframe.  I have already done this in android and it works very well.  In iOS however:

- Safari messes up the size of the frame.  I fixed this by setting the min-width css style to 100% for the frame.
- Scrolling on the iframe is always set to "no" even if you specify "yes.  I "fixed" this (so I thought) by using the only solution I could find which is to wrap the iframe in a div and scroll the div.  This made the header (position:fixed) scroll with the page when it should be fixed to the top of the page and broke other things on the page that rely on scroll position to trigger an action.  I also tried modifying the body of the content to contain css styles mentioned [here](https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix/blob/master/styles.css) but this didn't work either.  I was back to square one.

I have spent a total of a week researching how to fix this with no avail.  Recently I have discovered that loading my website in iOS's UIWebView or WKWebView works well to display the site exactly how I would expect.

That brings me to two possible solutions **(and my question)**:

1. Maybe I missed something with the css style on the content of the site.  I read that it is possible to get scrolling to work this way but I am sceptical because safari does not allow scrolling on an iframe.
2. (The likely solution but the one I cannot figure out) Make my cordova app use a one of iOS's webviews.  This is what I am having problems with.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  Is a webview an iframe? How do I use one of these webviews in my app? What does the index.html (cordova specific file) look like when I use a webview instead of an iframe (because currently this is where my iframe is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  Since I have access to the contents of the page, I added:

```
position:absolute
top: 0
right:0
bottom:0
left: 0
overflow-y: auto
overflow-x: hidden
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

To the scrolling body of the page.  This fixed my problem